# Mapping database date type to \datetime or any other object in Phalcon

Tags: php, orm, phalcon

I have a class which contains two other classes in its body:

```
class Leave
{
/**
 * @var Day
 */
private $fistDay;
/**
 * @var Day
 */
private $lastDay;
}
```

Day is a simple container over a php \Datetime class which implements some logic about operations on days to make code easier to read.

When I specify type of firstDay column in database as 'date', phalcon model generator maps it as 'string' while I'd like to use my custom class instead. Is there any way to do it? Making another table just for days seems to be an overkill ;-)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply some formatting after fetching data from database, Phalcon provides an [`afterFetch`](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#initializing-preparing-fetched-records) method you can implement on your model:

```
public function afterFetch()
{
    $this->firstDay = new Day($this->firstDay);
    $this->lastDay = new Day($this->lastDay);
}
```

I recommend looking into [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#events-and-events-manager) to see  some other events you can manage this way.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @yergo, that was the right place :) There's also need to use beforeSave() and afterSave() to make object string again before updating database record.

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->firstDay = $this->firstDay->getStringDate();
    $this->lastDay = $this->lastDay->getStringDate();
}

public function afterFetch()
{
    $this->firstDay = new Day($this->firstDay);
    $this->lastDay = new Day($this->lastDay);
}

public function afterSave()
{
    $this->firstDay = new Day($this->firstDay);
    $this->lastDay = new Day($this->lastDay);
}
```